# Excel Rotating Schedule

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a schedule to make.  One column is Times, the other column is Names. The times stay the same, but the Name column changes daily. The order of the Names stays the same, they just get rotated to a different time.

I'm looking for an easier way to rotate the Names instead of copy/paste.

Comment: Record a macro while you do the copy and paste. Edit the macro to suit your needs.

Comment: Are you saying that you randomly (or by other means), select the very first starting name, then everyone else in the list follows for subsequent times, looping back to the top of the list from the bottom, and the next day, repeat starting with the person in the list next after the previous starting person?  Do you have a 1:1 match in the count of names vs. time slots?  What happens is a person isn't available for their assigned time slot?  Is there a specific aspect of this that you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

How about if you could choose the first name from a dropdown list and then the rest of the names would fill in automatically?

[image]

In the screenshot above, there is a dropdown in `B2` where you can choose one of the names from the list in `E2:E9`.  That list can be hidden or located elsewhere if it needs to be.  Here's [how to make a dropdown list](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-drop-down-list-7693307a-59ef-400a-b769-c5402dce407b).

Then this formula, filled down from `B3`, fills in the rest of the names:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(D$2:D$9,MATCH(B2,D$2:D$9,0)+1),D$2)`

I hope this helps, and good luck.

Comment: This fills the list given the first name, but it doesn't automate or enforce the rotation.  :-)

Comment: I think what OP meant by rotation, was the order of the names stays the same, and "rotates" around to the first name after the last name.  Like what you said in your comment.  :-D